# how to concatenate text with image in a variable

Tags: javascript

Hello first i am basic to java script i have a some on mouse over divs which every one

contains information along images. the problem is that  i want to combine text with an image

inside a variable whenever i am mouse hovering each divs so the information along the image

should change as i did program for every one of them

the problem is that how to combine the text and image inside a variable

but i don't know how to do that here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ENGshowElements(){
        var Engineering = "Your In Engineering Section <br> <img src='a.jpg'>";

       document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Engineering;
    }
        function CONshowElements(){
        var Construction = "Your In Construction Section";

       document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Construction;
    }
        function LLCshowElements(){
        var LLCDubia = "Your In LLC Dubia Section";

       document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = LLCDubia;
    }
        function WASshowElements(){
        var WasteManagement = "Your In Waste Management Section";

       document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = WasteManagement;
    }
       function TRAshowElements(){
        var Transportation = "Your In Transportation Section";

       document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Transportation;
    }
           function LOGshowElements(){
        var Logistics = "Your In Logistics Section";

       document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Logistics;
    }
</script>




  <div class="firstbox" id="Engineering" onmouseover="ENGshowElements(); return false; " >Engineering</div>
  <div class="secbox" id="Construction"  onmouseover="CONshowElements(); return false; ">Construction</div>
  <div class="thirdbox" id="LLCDubia"  onmouseover="LLCshowElements(); return false; " >LLC Dubia</div>
  <div class="fourthbox" id="WasteManagement"  onmouseover="WASshowElements(); return false; " >Waste Management</div>
  <div class="fivthbox" id="Transportation"  onmouseover="TRAshowElements(); return false; " >Transportations</div>
  <div class="sixthbox" id="Logistics"  onmouseover="LOGshowElements(); return false; " >Logistics</div>
```

Comment: use css for god sake! You could add all content to the page with pictures and so on, use javascript to toggle classes to show/hide some elements. It will be much more easier

Comment: Also, you mean "You're"/"You are" not "Your".

Answer (score 0):

=> jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gy5rH/

just for the sake of making things clear, and pointing out that you're probably going the wrong way, here is a better alternative. It could probably be done mostly using css but here's something more easier to maintain.

Instead of using multiple triggers, We will use only one click function on every button. Each button will have a "data-target" which is the id of an other element.

Our markup will look like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    #source { display: none; }
  </style>
  <script>
   // Our click event
   function clickEvent (ev) {
     // Get the target in the dom
     // While checking more about event should be good because 
     // Target may not be the element you're looking for in some cases.
     var target = ev.target.dataset['target'];
     var obj = document.getElementById(target);

     // change the content with the one found
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = obj.innerHTML;
   }

   function loaded() {
     var docs = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
     // Transform to array 
     docs = Array.prototype.slice.call(docs);
     docs.forEach(function(elem) {
       // Assign click event to all elements
       elem.onclick = clickEvent;
     });
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loaded()">
  <div>
    <button class="btn" data-target="Engineering-Source">Engineering</button>
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="source">
    <div id="Engineering-Source">
      Your In Engineering Section <br> <img src='a.jpg'>
    </div>
    ...more after
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I added comments, but it's a nice way to do. Avoiding  "vanillajs" might not be a bad thing but. It can be done without much pain in vanillajs.

That said, here are some reasons why it's good. The content remains in the html instead of javascript. If a web spider will download your page, there are far more chances that it will look for html content instead of text in javascript source.

In my example, some things might not exists in old browser like "dataset" and "forEach".

## Note

That said, a pure "css" way of doing this is possible but might make the structure of the document harder to edit. On the other hand, there are ways to mix css and js to keep a minimum of js and as much as possible html/css to keep the styles in line.

Anyway, my example above should be working in some browsers to give an idea how to do it. I recommend using libraries like jQuery or prototype if you're not familiar with Javascript yet. The code above shouldn't definitely end up in production.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO: *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8BNG/1/)***

**HTML:**

```
<div class="firstbox" id="Engineering">Engineering</div>
<div class="secbox" id="Construction">Construction</div>
<div class="thirdbox" id="LLCDubia">LLC Dubia</div>
<div class="fourthbox" id="WasteManagement">Waste Management</div>
<div class="fivthbox" id="Transportation">Transportations</div>
<div class="sixthbox" id="Logistics">Logistics</div>
<div id="contents"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('Engineering').onmouseover = ENGshowElements;
document.getElementById('Construction').onmouseover = CONshowElements;
document.getElementById('LLCDubia').onmouseover = LLCshowElements;
document.getElementById('WasteManagement').onmouseover = WASshowElements;
document.getElementById('Transportation').onmouseover = TRAshowElements;
document.getElementById('Logistics').onmouseover = LOGshowElements;

function ENGshowElements() {
    var Engineering = "Your In Engineering Section <br> <img src='a.jpg'>";
    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Engineering;
}

function CONshowElements() {
    var Construction = "Your In Construction Section";

    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Construction;
}

function LLCshowElements() {
    var LLCDubia = "Your In LLC Dubia Section";

    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = LLCDubia;
}

function WASshowElements() {
    var WasteManagement = "Your In Waste Management Section";

    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = WasteManagement;
}

function TRAshowElements() {
    var Transportation = "Your In Transportation Section";

    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Transportation;
}

function LOGshowElements() {
    var Logistics = "Your In Logistics Section";

    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Logistics;
}
```